# Why can't I install MVC into an empty ASP Net Core project? (happens on both VS/Windows and Rider/Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've created an empty NET Core project, and my first step is simply installing MVC as I want to build a web app from scratch for learning purposes.

However, when I try to install MVC (`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc v5.2.3`) I get the same error in both Visual Studio on Windows, and Rider on Ubuntu from completely freshly generated projects.

Having looked at the Nuget logs, it seems like these are the main issues.

`...
ERROR: Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
...
ERROR: Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
ERROR: Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.3 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
ERROR: Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
...`

I only installed NET Core a week or two ago, and my Visual Studio/Rider are equally recent. This is into a fresh app, using the built in Nuget, so where am I going wrong?

I'm happy to provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your answer in the logs. 
**ERROR: Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1**.

If you need more info on .NET core please visit this blog by Scott Hanselman. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

Comment: Ah, I assumed that Nuget would only show Core comptabile packages. I guess I have more research to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the .Net Core you have to use MVC Core the one you are using is the regular MCV for .Net